# How to continually simplify derivatives of function defined in a system?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, simplifying-expressions

For example, if I input something like

```
b'[t_] = a[t];
a'[t_] = -Sin[b[t]];

a''[t]
```

it outputs just `a''[t]`.

Is there a way to get Mathematica to always simplify any derivatives of `a` and `b` to expressions only involving `a` and `b` (with no derivatives), so that whenever I type in something like `a''[t]` it outputs `-Cos[b[t]]a[t]`?

Comment: use `:=` instead of `=`?

Comment: That doesn't work for me

Comment: Did you `Clear` your variables?

Comment: Yes I did clear, but it still doesn't work.  Does it work for you?

Comment: `a[t_] := -Sin[f[t]];a''[t]`

Comment: @cvgmt I'm not sure what I should do with this

Comment: If clearing does not work, you need to start again in a fresh kernel. If @cvgmt's and your example still doesn't evaluate as expected, then please post screenshots and version information.

Comment: To evaluate `a''[t]` requires `a[t]` to be defined. Since only `a'[t]` is defined, you would need to enter `a''[t]`as `D[a'[t], t]`

Comment: Sorry - I see that cvgmt's example defines a[t] and not a'[t], and so it does work as his example intends but is different from my problem does not solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```
b' = a;
Derivative[n_?Positive][a] := Derivative[n-1][Function[-Sin[b[#]]]]
```

Then:

```
a''[t]
```

> -a[t] Cos[b[t]]

Comment: Yes thank you this does work if I do
`Derivative[n_?Positive][b] := Derivative[n - 1][Function[a[#]]]; 
Derivative[n_?Positive][a] := Derivative[n - 1][Function[-Sin[b[#]]]];`

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the `?Positive` part and the `#` is for?  I don't know much about mathematica.

Comment: @keagan_callis [`#]`(https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/4999) is short for `Slot[1]`, which represents the first argument to `Function`. `Derivative` operates only on functions, not expressions (one usually uses `D`, as in `D[expr, t]`, to operate on expressions).